# Adding NSArray items to UITableViewCell content view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsarray

In my app i am adding 3 UILabel to each Table view cell in the following way.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ShowMoreCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];
    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        [cell insertSubview:[items objectAtIndex:j] atIndex:j];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

Here items is an `NSMutableArray` and it has got elements of UILabel. I am trying to add three `labels` in each `cell`. But it is displaying the 3 `labels` only in last row.

Am i doing something wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: you are not reusing the cell but creating a new one everytime cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, which I think will cause you more memory problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add the same `UILabel` objects to different cells. `UIViews` (which `UITableViewCell` is a subclass of) can have only one parent view. You should create 3 new labels for every cell (if it doesn't contain them yet).

Answer (score 0):

The view objects eg labels are not supposed to be stored in any form. Best way to approach this problem would be to store the data items in the array and use cells to display those only.

Create a custom Cell say

`

```
MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property(nonatomic,strong)UILabel * lbl1;

@property(nonatomic,strong)UILabel * lbl2;

@property(nonatomic,strong)UILabel * lbl3;

@end;
```

Then set the values to these labels using like

```
cell.lbl1.text = @" some text";
cell.lbl2.text = @" some text";
cell.lbl3.text = @" some text";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *lblAdd=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 150, 20)];
lblAdd.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
lblAdd.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];



lblAdd.text=@"Label";
lblAdd.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblAdd];
```

That's it you will find labels in every row
Happy Coding